# Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AccountManagement' does not exist in the namespace 'System.DirectoryServices' (CS0234)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

first time using Visual Studio, I just received a new project and trying to run it. I get the following error `Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AccountManagement' does not exist in the namespace 'System.DirectoryServices' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (CS0234)`.

Any help would be much appreciated,
Thank you

Comment: either you have dependencies to install, or the program isn't in a compilable state. but maybe ask _whoever you received the project from_?

Comment: Seems like you need to install the nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/

Comment: The causes for the error you report are limited and clearly documented. See duplicates for extensive examples of how to fix this sort of error.

Answer (score -1):

Based on my research, maybe you are using the following similar code, which needs the namespace `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`.

```
 PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "Company");
```

As usual, we have two ways to solve it.

First, as others suggested, you can install nuget-package `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`.

[image]

Second, you can use visual-studio intellisense like the following:

[image]